# CMake with Xcode: configured header file (.h.in) not found

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode4, cmake, header-files

I'm working through the [CMake tutorial](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html) and I'm up to the *Adding a Version Number and Configured Header File* section. Unfortunately Xcode isn't recognising the generated header file:

The error:

[image: 'src/TutorialConfig' file not found]

The header file was generated by CMake ok:

[image: the header file in finder]

TutorialConfig.h.in

```
// the configured options and settings for Tutorial

#define Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR @Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR@
#define Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR @Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR@
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (Tutorial)
# The version number.
set (Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set (Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR 0)

# configure a header file to pass some of the CMake settings
# to the source code
configure_file (
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/TutorialConfig.h.in"
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/TutorialConfig.h"
  )

# add the binary tree to the search path for include files
# so that we will find TutorialConfig.h
include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/src")

# add the executable
add_executable(Tutorial src/tutorial.cpp)
```

[This is the tutorial I'm working from.](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, haha. I changed `#include "src/TutorialConfig.h"` to `#include "TutorialConfig.h"` and all is well. I figured it out by checking out the project settings:

[image: hooray!]

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Xcode, but another IDE that's Linux based.  But maybe I can help you a bit.  I'm just wondering -- does your program compile?  That's perhaps more important.

My IDE often complains about header files such as your's -- that is, configuration files that are generated by CMake.  Such warnings (at least for me) can be ignored.  I usually do because my build/ directory is sometimes empty.  So when I've opened up the source file, there wouldn't be TutorialConfig.h yet.

In fact, the IDE can never know about such header files.  That's because it doesn't know which build/ directory you're going to compile your program in.

If you are worried by the warning, then there is probably a place where you can specify to Xcode which build/ directory to search for header files.  That will remove the warning, after you've run CMake once.  However, removing such a warning is unreliable because you can always build in another directory that would have TutorialConfig.h missing.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I worked it out! `#include "TutorialConfig.h"` instead of `#include "src/TutorialConfig.h"`. facepalm. I'd answer myself, but I can't until another 8 hours. But thanks anyway!